# VM Group Policy Object

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, active-directory, group-policy

I have created a virtual machine as part of my home lab, to learn about AD and group policies etc.

I have created a group policy in the Domain Controller that disables the control panel, and have linked it to an Active Directory Group.

However I can't get the group policy to apply.

Does being a virtual machine affect this?

Thanks

Comment: “Does being a virtual machine affect this?” - It absolutely does not.  Sounds like the VM hasn’t been joined to the domain.

Comment: I have checked and it is connected to the domain, and I can login with users that I have created in AD, it also shows that the group policy has been added when I run "gpupdate /r"

Comment: Have you tried to reboot the machine?

Comment: I've decided that I will rebuild the machine and see how that goes.